# Cloudflare WARP not allowing telnet to 127.0.0.1 3306

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, cloudflare

I've recently started having issues with cloudflare WARP. I have the following setup.

`Ubuntu 22.04`
`Cloudflare-warp Version: 2024.2.62-1`
`Docker: 1.5-2`

When I connect to warp I have no problem accessing external addresses, but when I try to access my localhost I get rejected.

When I try to make SQL requests to the MySQL docker container without warp, it works without any problem. But if I try to connect to MySQL with warp enabled, I get the following error.

`Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.`

Connecting to the local apache docker website, I receive a `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR`

If I try to `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306` after a very short amount of time I get `Connection closed by foreign host.`

This behaviour only started recently and I don't believe any update triggered it. Any help would be appreciated.